# Time travel / accessing the fourth dimension

Tags: time-travel

There are a number of time travel movies where humans have gained access to the fourth dimension. Recent examples that come to mind are:

> Interstellar and (maybe) Arrival

In these movies the protagonist is able to pick a point in time and influence events at that point. The general idea being that we're 3-dimensional creatures and so have access to all 3 dimensions, but if we were to gain access to the 4th dimension then we would similarly be able to access all points along that dimension too

First, is this a fair understanding of time travel in movies?

Second, the issue I have with this idea is that while we're 3D creatures and have access to 3 dimensions, we don't have instantaneous access to it. We can't pick a location in 3D space and teleport there - we have to travel all points in between. So if we were to gain access to the 4th dimension, wouldn't we also have to travel across all points up to the selected time, instead of instantaneously jumping there?

An extreme example of this might be travelling a few hundred years into the future. If we do have to travel across all points in time first, then wouldn't the time traveler have to age accordingly?

Maybe my interpretation of time travel here is too strict, but how do movies generally deal with this? Are there any movies that address this issue?

Comment: If a 3 dimensional object moves off a 2 dimensional plane, and renters it at another point, it has teleported without traveling along that plane. You exist outside of that plane. Same must hold for time as a physical dimension. You exist outside of time.

Comment: But interstellar specifically avoids this. Cooper never enters 4 dimensional space. What he enters is the tesseract, a 3 dimensional construct of 4th dimensional space. He has to physically move along time external to him, while still experiencing normal time. Normal humans can't enter the bulk as they physically (pun intended) interact with it like the Bulk Beings (future humanity) do. The physicist who consulted for the movie wrote an entire book on it, I'm sure I'm explaining it badly.

Comment: "Is this a fair understanding of time travel in movies?"  How time travel works in any given movie is subject to the rules that movie invents concerning the subject.  Speaking in general, your understanding is as good a theory as any.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> First, is this a fair understanding of time travel in movies?

Broadly speaking, you are correct. The points I'm raising are nuances to your ideas, to show you why it's different from what you expect.

---

> humans have gained access to the fourth dimension (e.g. Interstellar)

As I understand it, Coop was *given* access to that specific four-dimensional space. He doesn't understand it (although he manages to at least do what he is expected to do there), but he does understand that (multidimensional) others have allowed him to be there.

> Second, the issue I have with this idea is that while we're 3D creatures and have access to 3 dimensions, we don't have instantaneous access to it. We can't pick a location in 3D space and teleport there - we have to travel all points in between.

You are right that time travel should almost always inherently mean the ability to teleport too. However, consider that a time machine can be built to **only** travel in time, like how an elevator only moves in one dimension.

However, if the time travel includes changing location (e.g. an American time travelling to ancient Egypt), then he must inherently be capable of teleportation too.

Do keep in mind that the connection between time travel and teleportation is not well understood by the general public (who generally do not see time as a dimension or understand its implications); and is therefore liable to be omitted from TV and movies, to avoid confusing the viewer.

> So if we were to gain access to the 4th dimension, wouldn't we also have to travel across all points up to the selected time, instead of instantaneously jumping there?

Spacetime, which is basically 4 dimensional time and space, has also brought forth the theory of [wormholes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wormhole). Wormholes are shortcuts that specifically **forgo the need to traverse all points** between the start and end of your journey, and immediately jump from the start to the end.
Assuming this is possible for spatial movement, this should also be possible for movement in time. Create a wormhole/rift to the correct destination, and travel through it.

However, even if we assume that wormholes do not exist, you've forgotten another option.
While it is true that we must then travel between all points between our start and end time; that says nothing about the **speed** at which we traverse these points. In this way, you could consider time travel to be like rewinding (or fastforwarding) a video tape. You're not immediately skipping to the right part (like a DVD allows you to do), but instead go through it at an increased rate, and have to decide for yourself when you slow down time again.

There is a Futurama episode that uses this method of time travel. It argues that time is cyclical, and the professor's machine can only go forward. Since time is cyclical, they can get back to the year 3000 by taking the long way round (the entire end and rebirth of the universe).
However, they keep overshooting their mark (because they need to manually stop fastforwarding), thus proving they are travelling by speeding things up, rather than travelling towards a preset destination.

> An extreme example of this might be travelling a few hundred years into the future. If we do have to travel across all points in time first, then wouldn't the time traveler have to age accordingly?

To use my analogy: Just because the video is fast-forwarded, does not mean the viewer is also aging at the same increased rate.
There is one case I've seen of the traveller aging according to the time he travels: [Click](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0389860/), the movie where Adam Sandler can skip ahead **in his own life**, and his biological age stays in sync with his surroundings (though his mind did not age accordingly).

Most, if not all time machines in media are assumed to make whoever uses the machine immune to the effects of time travel. If this immunity was not possible, then they would age at the same increased rate, but it would defeat the purpose of building a time machine for most plots that involve time travel.
Click is the only example I can think of where the time traveller ages accordingly.

---

It is interesting to note that there is a hard limit to how fast we can travel in space (i.e. light speed). There is currently no established lore for a hard limit on how fast you can let time fastforward.

Assuming there is no hard limit, you can let time go by *infinitely* fast, which is functionally the same as "instantaneous" time skipping.
But if there is a limit, then that is a consideration that must be taken into account, which would mean that travelling further in time takes longer (in "experienced time" during the travel).

*Edit: another interesting consideration, in my opinion, is whether the acceleration/deceleration of time is affected by inertia.*

> Maybe my interpretation of time travel here is too strict, but how do movies generally deal with this? Are there any movies that address this issue?

I think the main problem is that your understanding of spacetime far surpasses that of the average viewer, which makes it unlikely for TV and movies to currently spend time and effort on factual scientific correctness to the level that you (and me) are expecting.

If we can't even be bothered to show IT and programming correctly in this day and age, I have little hope for the correct visualization of the theoretical concept of time travel.

Answer (score 4):

Mathematically, it depends on the shape or curvature of the 3rd dimension.   Consider a more tangible example.   Two people on opposite sides of the Earth are 1 earth diameter apart (about 7,900 miles apart as the neutrino flies).   But by plane, it's 1/2 Earth circumference or 12,500 miles.   By stepping into another dimension, you could in theory travel straight and reduce 4,600 miles from your journey.

If all the dimensions are set up like blocks - perfectly flat, so to speak, then you're correct in thinking that you'd still have to travel said distance either way.   Your logic is sound, though it's a little unclear if you step into a time dimension, how much "time" it takes to travel through time, the HG wells time machine traveled a year per second as I recall.  Doc Brown's was more instantaneous).   But it's also possible that by re-shaping the dimensions, with curves or angles, travel could become shorter or longer by stepping into another dimension - similar to how traveling through the earth is shorter than traveling around it.

One of the movies you mention got around that by a spinning black hole and super-gravity, which in a sense, slows time down and makes traveling great distances in an instant possible.    That's still a bit of a stretch as far as real science goes, but the black hole stops time element works.   That's like squeezing time into an instant.

Relativity is both useful and not that useful for time travel.  If you travel at the speed of light, the universe basically flattens into 2 dimensions and the direction you're traveling, you get there in an instant, but to people watching you, it still takes 1 year per light year, so to you it's instant, to the people around you, years pass, but if you could travel through time that way, it wouldn't matter, it would still just be an instant to the traveler.   Being able to travel vast distances in an instant, and at the same time, travel through time - problem solved.

Other things to possibly consider would be momentum.   Earth moves through space.   If you maintain that momentum stepping through into another dimension, perhaps you could use it.   There's almost always a way to cheat if you're a writer.    Fringe did something clever with their dual worlds.   When they kidnapped the lead character from an elevator, they had to return her with the same momentum, so upon returning she flew through a car windshield.

There's no one way to deal with it.   That kind of travel can be as hard or as easy as the author wants.   In 12 Monkeys, there were some kinks to be worked out and some problems sending people back to the right time.

@CDE is correct.   Interstellar did consult a physicist (Kip Thorne), but the physics was heavy on the theoretical, and by no means mainstream or what I might call "real" physics.   There are explanations for most of the stuff that was done in interstellar but if you said to your college advisor that you'd like your thesis to be on the physics of interstellar, he'd probably ask you to pick another major.